# How to transform a rational function to get desired factor

Tags: pattern-matching

I have an expression like this

```
-t^-b + (t - t^(1/2 + 1/(8 k)))^-b
```

I would like to transform it to get

```
t^-b (-1 + ((1 - t^(1/8 (-4 + 1/k))))^-b)
```

In particular, I want the term `t^(1/8 (-4 + 1/k))` to appear. How can I do this without copying and modifying the equation by hand?

Update: Using

```
Factor[-t^-b + (t - t^(1/2 + 1/(8 k)))^-b]
```

gives

```
t^-b (t - t^(1/2 + 1/(8 k)))^-b (t^b - (t - t^(1/2 + 1/(8 k)))^b)
```

But how can I take out a factor of `t` from `t - t^(1/2 + 1/(8 k))`?

Comment: How about the result of `Factor[-t^-b + (t - t^(1/2 + 1/(8 k)))^-b]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us introduce a function `factor` that will be able to factorize the expression taking out a desired multiplicand:

```
factor[expr_, fact_, fun1_ : Expand, fun2_ : Identity] := 
 Module[{a = fact, b = expr/fact},fun2[Evaluate[a]]*fun1[Evaluate[b]]]
```

This is the expression:

```
expr = -t^-b + (t - t^(1/2 + 1/(8 k)))^-b;
```

By applying the function `factor` as follows

```
factor[expr, t^-b, Simplify[#, t > 0] &]
```

one finds the desired result.

Have fun!